# iOS WKWebView request on custom protocol (schema) is blocked

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

Not able to request on custom protocol from an HTTPS website running inside WKWebview, trying to load glb file. It's working for .png file, so I suspect it's because of the browser is blocking a request on non-HTTPS URL from a HTTPS site.

Error

[Warning] [blocked] The page at https://abc.xyz.in/something/0 was not allowed to display insecure content from customsource://something.cloudfront.net/assets/models/something.glb. (ff8f759459f7.js, line 2)

tried the following config

```
App Transport Security Settings
-Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES
-Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content = YES
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WKWebview \[Warning\] \[blocked\] The page at https://www.myurl.com was not allowed to display insecure content from mycustomscheme://?path=somepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773828/wkwebview-warning-blocked-the-page-at-https-www-myurl-com-was-not-allowed)

Comment: @timbretimbre I tried it but does not work